# searching in db for my web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

currently i am working on a webbased project using mvc3 asp.net. i am using codefirst technique here. And angularjs as scripting framework.
the scenario for which i will need help is like below,

i have a model called employee

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and each employee can have preference/preferences.
model class for Preference is like below

```
public class Preference 
{
    public int PreferenceId { get; set; } 
    public string Preference { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i am generating Employee list i want to show delete button only beside those who have no preference . For  that i have to see for each employee in database if he has any preference. But it's making my program run slowly.

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeesList()
{
    var employees = new List<object>();
    foreach (var employee in EmployeeRepository.GetAll())
    {
        employees.Add(new{EmployeeId=employee.EmployeeId,Name=employee.Name,
        Deletable=IsEmployeeDeletable(employee.EmployeeId)});
    }
    return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

i am calling the following function for each employee. so for each employee there is a searching in preference table and the whole list is coming too slowly

```
private bool IsEmployeeDeletable(int EmployeeId)
{
    return !PreferenceRepository.GetConditional
              (p => p.EmployeeId==EmployeeId).ToList().Any();
}
```

Is there any way so that i dont have to do this in this way and i can improve the efficiency and time for propagating this list?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a preferences property to the employee:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Preference> Preferences {get;set;}
}
```

The the controller method can just do one call to the db to get the list of employees that will have the preferences linked to them.

```
 public ActionResult GetEmployeesList()
{
    var employees = EmployeeRepository.GetAll();
    return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in your HTML you can access the Preferences property from the Json object, so to show the button for only those without preferences I would put a condition on the button like so:

`<input type="button" ng-click="deleteEmployee()" ng-show="!employee.Preferences.Length">Delete</input>`

Comment: thanks for your response. 
i thought something like that. but is it wise design of employee model. keeping list of preferences in it?
just need some suggestion regarding this as my database related knowledge is very poor